# Add to a value read into a JCL

Tags: jcl

I am working on writing a JCL which will read an option card containing a date. I need the date that is read in +1 and +2. Is there a way for me to do this in my JCL?

For example, my option card might contain: 20150923

I, for other pieces of my JCL, need: 20150924 and 20150925

Comment: No. Did you look at the JCL Reference? Dates in JOBs are often from the Scheduler. Dates in applications from a Calendar File.

Comment: As Bill said No, what are you actually trying to do ???; you can generate jobs etc there is probably a way of achieving what you want

Answer (score 0):

Best here is to use REXX to either generate a job or have a written template that you modify and submit.
With REXX you would have to open the file/dataset that you obtain the 'option card' , save that to a variable and later on pass it to the edited JCL.
At the end You can submit the job or do it later manually.

Regards,
Jarek.

Here is a nice example. Bit of a long read but it's [Using a batch REXX procedure to generate a unique output data set name](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQJMU_5.2.0/dwwig/dwwig000172.html)